# can't locate reference assembly despite being already listed as a reference

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, reference, .net-assembly

I get the following error message when I try to compile a solution that I downloaded from an external trusted souce: abcName

"Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly."

Yet the assembly "abcName" is there, and it is listed under References.  And if I try to manually add it as a reference, it says it already is a reference.

Comment: Is there any warning/error symbol on the reference - such as perhaps its for a different version of .net

Comment: and what is `abcName`???

Comment: have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding?

Comment: have you tried removing and readding as a reference?

Comment: @psubsee2003,  Bingo!  You win the prize.  To answer the runners-up: There was no other warrning error Symbol.  "abcName" is the name of the Assembly.  And I had already cleaned/rebuilt.

Comment: I will add it as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I do when I run into this issue (after cleaning and re-building) is removing and re-adding the reference.  That usually resolves most of my issues,.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing and adding it again as this will refresh the file path, which may be pointing to the wrong place.

If you select the reference and press f4 if the path is blank then it cant find the reference but it will stop you from re adding it.